# "NULL expression encountered" on FTDI's libMPSSE

Tags: ftdi

My question is specific to the library libMPSSE from FTDI to work with USB to serial port (SPI, I2C, etc) adapters on Linux.

When I execute any program linked with the library, the method Init_libMPSSE() is called (without explicit invocation) and throws the following message.

```
../../Infra/src/ftdi_infra.c:243:Init_libMPSSE(): NULL expression encountered
```

Has anybody experienced this issue and found a workaround?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error when libMPSSE can't open the libftd2xx.so shared library. You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path where this library was installed. For example if the library is in /usr/local/lib you would run the SPI static example like this:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./sample-static.o
```

Comment: My workaround is to call dlopen and dlclose for libftd2xx.so to ensure that this shared library is available before calling Init_libMPSSE().

This is important for me because Init_libMPSSE() calls exit(1) to end the program if the shared library cannot be loaded and I do not want this to happen.

You can download the LibMPSSE-I2C source code from here to see  how Init_libMPSSE() works:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-I2C.htm

Answer (score 0):

### A:

Using:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./your_application
```

is only one of the important steps!

> **Important:** not using `sudo` can result in a failure like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829163/init-libmpsse-status-spi-getnumchannelsnochannels-always-returns-0)!

### B:

But on **Linux** make sure that before you execute the command above, you disable the FTDI's VCP drivers that are already included in the Linux kernel. VCP drivers and `libftd2xx` drivers cant coexist! So, even before you execute the command above, you have to (a) plug in the device and (b) dissable the VCP drivers:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/3
  └─> sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/3
  └─> sudo rmmod usbserial
```

Now, your application will be able to talk with `libftd2xx` drivers because VCP drivers will not interfere. So now you can execute the command in **A:**.

### C:

Pay attention that bitness of the `libMPSSE` *(& therefore your application)* and `libftd2xx` have to also be the same! 32-bit or 64 bit!

For **Linux**, FTDI only provides 32-bit precompiled `libMPSSE` library [here](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/libMPSSE.zip), but they provide 32-bit and 64-bit `libftd2xx` drivers [here](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/). So if you installed 64-bit `libftd2xx`, you need to compile the 64-bit `libMPSSE` library yourself! Sources are available [here](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/libMPSSE_Source.zip).

If we are on 64-bit system, we download the sources and we will get the compressed file `libMPSSE_Source.zip`. We extract it:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> unzip libMPSSE_Source.zip
```

and we will get a folder `libMPSSE__0-6_Source`.  We move inside and *try* to build the library!

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> cd ./libMPSSE__0-6_Source/LibMPSSE/
  
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > LibMPSSE
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> cp ../External/Linux/libftd2xx1.1.12/release/ftd2xx.h .

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > LibMPSSE
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> cp ../External/Linux/libftd2xx1.1.12/release/WinTypes.h .
  
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > LibMPSSE
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> gcc -Wall -c *.c
ftdi_mid.c: In function ‘Mid_CheckMPSSEAvailable’:
ftdi_mid.c:653:2: error: unknown type name ‘byte’
  653 |  byte los = strlen(devList.Description);
      |  ^~~~
```

We will see that there is an error but it is fixable. We just open a file `ftdi_mid.h` and move to the line `653` which we edit like this:

```
unsigned char los = strlen(devList.Description);
```

Now we compile `.h` files to `.o` files and create an archive  i.e. static library `libMPSSE.a`:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > LibMPSSE
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> gcc -Wall -c *.c

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > LibMPSSE
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> ar -cvq libMPSSE.a *.o 
a - ftdi_common.o
a - ftdi_i2c.o
a - ftdi_infra.o
a - ftdi_mid.o
a - ftdi_spi.o
```

We can now also move this 64-bit library in our project's folder and we can use this one, but doing this would demand us to remove or rename the 32-bit libraries that are already there.

### D:

To compile my application with 32-bit libraries, I used:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -g -gdwarf-2 -m32 -L. -o main.elf main.c -lMPSSE -ldl
```

> Note that I am on Debian 11 and in order to crosscompile with `-m32` flag, you need to install the package `gcc-multiarch`.

But to compile my application with 64-bit libraries, I used:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -g -gdwarf-2 -L. -o main.elf main.c -lMPSSE -ldl
```