# Init_libMPSSE(), status = SPI_GetNumChannels(noChannels); always returns 0

Tags: c, driver, ftdi

I am using FT2232H-56Q. I want to use the SPI channels. I downloaded [the libMPSSE-SPI example](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI.htm).

I am using the sample example "sample-static.c". When I run the exe I always get this message:

> Press any key to continue . . . Number of available SPI channels = 0

This happens even when the device is connected.

Code:

```
/*!
 * \file sample-static.c
 *
 * \author FTDI
 * \date 20110512
 *
 * Copyright © 2000-2014 Future Technology Devices International Limited
 *
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY FUTURE TECHNOLOGY DEVICES INTERNATIONAL LIMITED ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS
 * OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL FUTURE TECHNOLOGY DEVICES INTERNATIONAL LIMITED
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF
 * THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * Project: libMPSSE
 * Module: SPI Sample Application - Interfacing 94LC56B SPI EEPROM
 *
 * Rivision History:
 * 0.1  - 20110512 - Initial version
 * 0.2  - 20110801 - Changed LatencyTimer to 255
 *                   Attempt to open channel only if available
 *                   Added & modified macros
 *                   Included stdlib.h
 * 0.3  - 20111212 - Added comments
 * 0.41 - 20140903 - Fixed compilation warnings
 *                   Added testing of SPI_ReadWrite()
 */

/******************************************************************************/
/*                           Include files                                         */
/******************************************************************************/
/* Standard C libraries */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <assert.h>
//#include <vector.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//#include <random>

/* OS specific libraries */
#ifdef _WIN32
#include<windows.h>
#endif

/* Include D2XX header*/
#include "ftd2xx.h"

/* Include libMPSSE header */
#include "libMPSSE_spi.h"

/******************************************************************************/
/*                              Macro and type defines                             */
/******************************************************************************/
/* Helper macros */

#define APP_CHECK_STATUS(exp) {if(exp!=FT_OK){printf("%s:%d:%s(): status(0x%x) \
!= FT_OK\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__,exp);exit(1);}else{;}};
#define CHECK_NULL(exp){if(exp==NULL){printf("%s:%d:%s():  NULL expression \
encountered \n",__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);exit(1);}else{;}};

/* Application specific macro definations */
#define SPI_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE      256
#define SPI_WRITE_COMPLETION_RETRY      10
#define START_ADDRESS_EEPROM    0x00 /*read/write start address inside the EEPROM*/
#define END_ADDRESS_EEPROM      0x10
#define RETRY_COUNT_EEPROM      10  /* number of retries if read/write fails */
#define CHANNEL_TO_OPEN         0   /*0 for first available channel, 1 for next... */
#define SPI_SLAVE_0             0
#define SPI_SLAVE_1             1
#define SPI_SLAVE_2             2
#define DATA_OFFSET             4
#define USE_WRITEREAD           0

/******************************************************************************/
/*                              Global variables                                    */
/******************************************************************************/
static FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
static uint8 buffer[SPI_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
static FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *devList;
static uint32 numberChannels;
/******************************************************************************/
/*                      Public function definitions                                */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief Initializes the comBridge
* Must be called first
* @param[out] noChannels: Number of available channels
* @param[out] channelId[]: Description of the devices with their index being identical to the channel selector in all other functions
* @return Device status with FT_OK = 0
*/
FT_STATUS comBridge_initialize(uint32 *noChannels, char *channelId[]) {
    Init_libMPSSE();

    FT_STATUS status = FT_OK;

    // get number of channels
    status = SPI_GetNumChannels(noChannels);
    numberChannels = *noChannels;
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
#ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("ComBridge initialized\n");
    printf("  SPI channels %d\n\n", *noChannels);
#endif // VERBOSE

    // get channel infos
    devList = (FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *)calloc(*noChannels, sizeof(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE));
    for (uint32 channelIndex = 0; channelIndex < *noChannels; channelIndex++) {
        status = SPI_GetChannelInfo(channelIndex, devList);
        APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
        strcpy(channelId[channelIndex],  devList->Description);
#ifdef VERBOSE
        printf("Channel %d info\n", channelIndex);
        printf("  Flags        0x%x\n", devList->Flags);
        printf("  Type         0x%x\n", devList->Type);
        printf("  ID           0x%x\n", devList->ID);
        printf("  LocId        0x%x\n", devList->LocId);
        printf("  SerialNumber %s\n", devList->SerialNumber);
        printf("  Description  %s\n", devList->Description);
        //printf("  ftHandle=0x%x\n", (unsigned int)devList->ftHandle);
        printf("\n");
#endif // VERBOSE
    };
    return status;
}

/**
* @brief Opens and initilizes a SPI channel
* Must be called after comBridge_initialize() and for each channel individually
* Latency = 255 ms, that "xDBUS3 of MPSSE is chip select" and that "chip select is active high" are predefined and cannot be changed manually
* @param[in] channel: Selects a channel via the index of the corresponding element in the channelId[] array
* @param[in] clockRate_Hz: Clock rate of the SPI bus in Hz (0..10 MHz)
* @param[in] spiMode: Selects SPI Mode (SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0 or SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE3)
* @return Device status with FT_OK = 0
*/
FT_STATUS comBridge_setup(uint32 channel, uint32 clockRate_Hz, uint32 spiMode) {
    FT_STATUS status = FT_OK;

    assert(channel < numberChannels);
    assert(clockRate_Hz <= 10000000);
    assert((spiMode == SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0) | (spiMode == SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE3));

    status = SPI_OpenChannel(channel, &devList[channel].ftHandle);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    ChannelConfig channelConf = {
        5000, // ClockRate
        255, // LatencyTime
        SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS3 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_ACTIVELOW, // configOptions
        0x00000000 // Pin
    };
    channelConf.ClockRate = clockRate_Hz;
    channelConf.configOptions = spiMode | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS3 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_ACTIVELOW;
    status = SPI_InitChannel(devList[channel].ftHandle, &channelConf);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

#ifdef VERBOSE
    printf("Channel %d opened\n", channel);
    printf("  ClockRate    %d\n", channelConf.ClockRate);
    printf("  Latency      %d\n", channelConf.LatencyTimer);
    printf("  Config       %d\n", channelConf.configOptions);
    printf("  Pin          %d\n\n", channelConf.Pin);
    //printf("  Handle=%ld\n", (uint32)devList[channel].ftHandle);
#endif // VERBOSE

    // sets all GPIO pins as input
    status = FT_WriteGPIO(devList[channel].ftHandle, 0b00000000, 0b00000000);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
    return status;
}


/*!
 * \brief Writes to EEPROM
 *
 * This function writes a byte to a specified address within the 93LC56B EEPROM
 *
 * \param[in] slaveAddress Address of the I2C slave (EEPROM)
 * \param[in] registerAddress Address of the memory location inside the slave to where the byte
 *          is to be written
 * \param[in] data The byte that is to be written
 * \return Returns status code of type FT_STATUS(see D2XX Programmer's Guide)
 * \sa Datasheet of 93LC56B http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21794F.pdf
 * \note
 * \warning
 */
static FT_STATUS read_byte(uint8 slaveAddress, uint8 address, uint16 *data)
{
    uint32 sizeToTransfer = 0;
    uint32 sizeTransfered;
    uint8 writeComplete=0;
    uint32 retry=0;
    FT_STATUS status;

    /* CS_High + Write command + Address */
    sizeToTransfer=1;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0] = 0xC0;/* Write command (3bits)*/
    buffer[0] = buffer[0] | ( ( address >> 3) & 0x0F );/*5 most significant add bits*/
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /*Write partial address bits */
    sizeToTransfer=4;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0] = ( address & 0x07 ) << 5; /* least significant 3 address bits */
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /*Read 2 bytes*/
    sizeToTransfer=2;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    status = SPI_Read(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    *data = (uint16)(buffer[1]<<8);
    *data = (*data & 0xFF00) | (0x00FF & (uint16)buffer[0]);

    return status;
}

/*!
 * \brief Reads from EEPROM
 *
 * This function reads a byte from a specified address within the 93LC56B EEPROM
 *
 * \param[in] slaveAddress Address of the I2C slave (EEPROM)
 * \param[in] registerAddress Address of the memory location inside the slave from where the
 *          byte is to be read
 * \param[in] *data Address to where the byte is to be read
 * \return Returns status code of type FT_STATUS(see D2XX Programmer's Guide)
 * \sa Datasheet of 93LC56B http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21794F.pdf
 * \note
 * \warning
 */
static FT_STATUS write_byte(uint8 slaveAddress, uint8 address, uint16 data)
{
    uint32 sizeToTransfer = 0;
    uint32 sizeTransfered=0;
    uint8 writeComplete=0;
    uint32 retry=0;
    FT_STATUS status;

    /* Write command EWEN(with CS_High -> CS_Low) */
    sizeToTransfer=11;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0]=0x9F;/* SPI_EWEN -> binary 10011xxxxxx (11bits) */
    buffer[1]=0xFF;
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /* CS_High + Write command + Address */
    sizeToTransfer=1;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0] = 0xA0;/* Write command (3bits) */
    buffer[0] = buffer[0] | ( ( address >> 3) & 0x0F );/*5 most significant add bits*/
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /*Write 3 least sig address bits */
    sizeToTransfer=3;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0] = ( address & 0x07 ) << 5; /* least significant 3 address bits */
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /* Write 2 byte data + CS_Low */
    sizeToTransfer=2;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0] = (uint8)(data & 0xFF);
    buffer[1] = (uint8)((data & 0xFF00)>>8);
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

    /* Wait until D0 is high */
#if 1
    /* Strobe Chip Select */
    sizeToTransfer=0;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
#ifndef __linux__
    Sleep(10);
#endif
    sizeToTransfer=0;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
#else
    retry=0;
    state=FALSE;
    SPI_IsBusy(ftHandle,&state);
    while((FALSE==state) && (retry<SPI_WRITE_COMPLETION_RETRY))
    {
        printf("SPI device is busy(%u)\n",(unsigned)retry);
        SPI_IsBusy(ftHandle,&state);
        retry++;
    }
#endif
    /* Write command EWEN(with CS_High -> CS_Low) */
    sizeToTransfer=11;
    sizeTransfered=0;
    buffer[0]=0x8F;/* SPI_EWEN -> binary 10011xxxxxx (11bits) */
    buffer[1]=0xFF;
    status = SPI_Write(ftHandle, buffer, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransfered,
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE|
        SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
    return status;
}

/*!
 * \brief Main function / Entry point to the sample application
 *
 * This function is the entry point to the sample application. It opens the channel, writes to the
 * EEPROM and reads back.
 *
 * \param[in] none
 * \return Returns 0 for success
 * \sa
 * \note
 * \warning
 */
int main()
{
    uint32 noChannels = 0;
    char *channelId[10];
    char channelIdArray[10][46] = { { '\0' } };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(channelId); i++)
        channelId[i] = channelIdArray[i];
    comBridge_initialize(&noChannels, channelId);
    for (uint32 channel = 0; channel < noChannels; channel++)
    {
        //cout << "Channel " << channel << ": " << channelId[channel] << endl;
        comBridge_setup(channel, 100000, SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0);

        comBridge_release(channel);
    }


    FT_STATUS status = FT_OK;
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE devList = {0};
    ChannelConfig channelConf = {0};
    uint8 address = 0;
    uint32 channels = 0;
    uint16 data = 0;
    uint8 i = 0;
    uint8 latency = 255;    

    channelConf.ClockRate = 5000;
    channelConf.LatencyTimer = latency;
    channelConf.configOptions = SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0 | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS3;// | SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_ACTIVELOW;
    channelConf.Pin = 0x00000000;/*FinalVal-FinalDir-InitVal-InitDir (for dir 0=in, 1=out)*/

    /* init library */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    Init_libMPSSE();
#endif
    status = SPI_GetNumChannels(&channels);
    APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
    printf("Number of available SPI channels = %d\n",(int)channels);

    if(channels>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<channels;i++)
        {
            status = SPI_GetChannelInfo(i,&devList);
            APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
            printf("Information on channel number %d:\n",i);
            /* print the dev info */
            printf("        Flags=0x%x\n",devList.Flags);
            printf("        Type=0x%x\n",devList.Type);
            printf("        ID=0x%x\n",devList.ID);
            printf("        LocId=0x%x\n",devList.LocId);
            printf("        SerialNumber=%s\n",devList.SerialNumber);
            printf("        Description=%s\n",devList.Description);
            printf("        ftHandle=0x%x\n",(unsigned int)devList.ftHandle);/*is 0 unless open*/
        }

        /* Open the first available channel */
        status = SPI_OpenChannel(CHANNEL_TO_OPEN,&ftHandle);
        APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
        printf("\nhandle=0x%x status=0x%x\n",(unsigned int)ftHandle,status);
        status = SPI_InitChannel(ftHandle,&channelConf);
        APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);

#if USE_WRITEREAD   
        {
            uint8 k,l;
            uint8 inBuffer[100];
            uint8 outBuffer[]={0x81,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39};
            uint32 sizeToTransfer,sizeTransferred;
            for(k=0; k<5; k++)
            {
                printf("LoopCount = %u ",(unsigned)k);
                sizeToTransfer=10;
                sizeTransferred=0;
#if 1 // BYTES
                status = SPI_ReadWrite(ftHandle, inBuffer, outBuffer+k, sizeToTransfer, &sizeTransferred,
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES|
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE|
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
#else // BITES
                status = SPI_ReadWrite(ftHandle, inBuffer, outBuffer+k, sizeToTransfer*8, &sizeTransferred,
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS|
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE|
                    SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE);
#endif
                APP_CHECK_STATUS(status);
                printf("status=0x%x sizeTransferred=%u\n", status, sizeTransferred);
                for(l=0;l<sizeToTransfer;l++)
                    printf("0x%x\n",(unsigned)inBuffer[l]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }       
#else // USE_WRITEREAD
        for(address=START_ADDRESS_EEPROM;address<END_ADDRESS_EEPROM;address++)
        {
            printf("writing address = %02d data = %d\n",address,address+DATA_OFFSET);
            write_byte(SPI_SLAVE_0, address,(uint16)address+DATA_OFFSET);
        }

        for(address=START_ADDRESS_EEPROM;address<END_ADDRESS_EEPROM;address++)
        {
            read_byte(SPI_SLAVE_0, address,&data);
            printf("reading address = %02d data = %d\n",address,data);
        }
#endif // USE_WRITEREAD

        status = SPI_CloseChannel(ftHandle);
    }

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    Cleanup_libMPSSE();
#endif

#ifndef __linux__
    system("pause");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution? I have the same trouble. Tried few different ftdi chips ft2242h and few versions of dll. Not helped.

Comment: @Aave i tried with the 32 bit libMPSSE.lib and it worked for me. your problem could be diiferent i suppose

Comment: I checked it under Windows XP x86, and it works. But under Win 7 x64 does not. LibMPSSE.dll operates with d2xx.dll, any way. Probably, the problem caused by interoperate of different versions of dlls.

Comment: @Aave sorry i meant 32 bit libMPSSE.dll  i am also working on have a 64 bit machine and 64 bit win 7. just try with 32 bit .dll

Comment: It's strange, but under Win 8 and Win 10, x64, it's works. Only Win 7 does not.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problem with FT2232H / win7Pro.

The root cause is libMPSSE get wrong locID and judge that the device is not available since D2XX always returns LocId=0 to libMPSSE.

ftdi_mid.c

```
    case FT_DEVICE_2232H:
        if(((devList.LocId & 0xf)==1)|| ((devList.LocId & 0xf)==2))
        {
            isMPSSEAvailable =  MID_MPSSE_AVAILABLE;
        }
        break;
```

I modify the condition and re-compile libMPSSE with mingw64. It just works.

Comment: I tried this, but did not solve my problem. What was your library version?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 19.10. The root cause of this was the kernel module that was interacting with FTDI once it was connected and preventing me to connect with it.

The solution was to unload that kernel module:

```
sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
```

It is also mentioned in the libftd2xx `ReadMe` file:

```
If the message "FT_Open failed" appears:
Perhaps the kernel automatically loaded another driver for the 
FTDI USB device.

sudo lsmod

If "ftdi_sio" is listed:
    Unload it (and its helper module, usbserial), as follows.

    sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
    sudo rmmod usbserial

Otherwise, it's possible that libftd2xx does not recognise your 
device's Vendor and Product Identifiers.  Call FT_SetVIDPID before
calling FT_Open/FT_OpenEx/FT_ListDevices.
```

Comment: This is not the case. I did remove both modules `ftdi_sio` and `usbseral` but I keep on getting the same message.

Comment: For me solution was to execute the program as `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a letter to FTDI Chip with the question. The support send an updated library that works. The version of library is 0.6 (beta).